# Need help in parsing the below using reex

Tags: json, regex, parsing

I am zero in regex and need help in parsing the value for key "access_token" from the below output.This will be later used in passing as variable for another function.
So basically the regex should only fetch

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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.qYID1b5lMjFhn7fTcSX5v6K6z2YpGJwAvE4gQfVrhxo
```

Here is the output of my Post output

```
{
    "access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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.qYID1b5lMjFhn7fTcSX5v6K6z2YpGJwAvE4gQfVrhxo",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "expires_in": 2999,
    "refresh_token": "65be41084c0b4adeaeec9725cb2e6240",
    "audience": "1412001",
    "displayName": "Lokesh",
    "userId": "testuser78",
    "rolesandpermission": "HELPDESK:9030,9000,9028,9027,9026,9025,9024,9023,9022,9021,9020,9019,9018,9013,9012,9011,9010,9009,9008,9007,9006,9005,9004,9003,9002,9001,9029",
    "resChannelID": "19",
    "Client": "FYC",
    "isAptClnt": "True",
    "scope": "apt:FYC env:PROD role:HELPDESK",
    ".issued": "Sun, 07 Oct 2018 12:17:29 GMT",
    ".expires": "Sun, 07 Oct 2018 13:07:29 GMT"
}
```

Comment: [As with HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#1732454), you can't use a single regular expression to parse JSON. As with HTML, you'll be tricked into thinking "Oh, but this is a simple, contained use case..." Don't be. :-) Use a parser. If you'd told us what environment you want to do this in (JavaScript, Java, PHP, C#, Ruby, ...) we could have pointed you at how you parse JSON in that environment.

Comment: Using regex? I suppose you should be using a better library that's designed specifically for JSON.

Comment: you should use JSON.parse instead of using regex

Answer (score 0):

Simple PCRE look like

```
\"access_token\":.\"(.+?)\"
```

And you will get your token in fast captured group 
You can practice with this regex on this website
https://regex101.com/